# filter keys out from list of dicts

Tags: python

Say I have a list of `dict`:

```
ld = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':9},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':10}]
```

And a list to filter the keys out:

```
l = ['a','c']
```

Want to remove key `a` and `c` from `ld`:

Try:

```
result = [d for d in ld for k in d if k in l]
```

Desired Result:

```
[{'b':2},{'b':2}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your outer container needs to be a list : use a (1 dimension) list comprehension
- Your inner container needs to be a dict : ues a dict comprehension

For you now you're using a 2d list comprehension

---

The filtering part should be at the dict level

```
ld = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 10}]
l = ['a', 'c']
result = [{k: v for k, v in subdict.items() if k not in l}
          for subdict in ld]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly compressed and that makes it hard to understand and easy for bugs to hide.

Here you want to "filter" a list of dicts and remove entries from each dicht that is not in the filter list. So my first suggestion is to rename your variables:

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 10}]
excludes = ['a', 'c']
```

Now you need to unpack a `list`, and then the inner `dict`. Currently you are trying to use the list iteration on both. You want `items()` to iterate over `(key, value)` pairs.

Further, you are filtering on the outer list level, while the keys to filter live in the inner dict.

Here is my solution

```
result = []
for entry in data:
    # entry is now one of the dicts
    result.append({key:value for key, value in entry.items() if key not in excludes})
```

You can compress this again in a single line, if you really want to. But in my opinion (while not playing [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)) readability beats compressedness.

Comment: If you want full readability , don't make a loop on the dict, to use a dict-comprehension (where resides the hard part), make a for-loop for the dict too

Comment: I don't see my code as overly compressed, perhaps the variables names are short and `compressed` as you said.

Comment: @azro totally agree, that would be even better! Thanks for pointing that out. Here, I decided to stay as much in the authors style as I was "willing to accept".

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple writing method is clearer when there are many cycles

```py
ld = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':9},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':10}]

l = ['a','c']
for d in ld:
    for r in l:
        if r in d:
            del d[r]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative filtering whether keys in `ld` are not in `l`:

```
result = [{k:d[k]} for d in ld for k in d if k not in l]
```